# Should "deep-space-network" and "dsn" be merged?

Tags: discussion

Should the tags [deep-space-network](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-space-network) and [dsn](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dsn) be merged?

See [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15540/12102) for example.

Also, I used the `optical` for optical communications, it seems like a vague tag but maybe that's fine for now.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and done.

In the future, you have enough reputation where you can suggest such synonyms yourself. If they don't get the attention, then bring it up here or in the chat, and we can take care of it. You would have gotten a badge if you had done so, but I went ahead and took care of it.

Comment: Thanks and thanks! Good to know the additional info!

Comment: I started the tag `near-earth-asteroid`, used it twice, then noticed the `neo` tag exists already. They are not actually synonymous (I think) because objects are not necessarily asteroids. One way to solicit opions is to suggest synonymization. Since I don't use `neo` I think I don't have sufficient privilege. I'm also not sure what happens. Will the synonym continue to appear as an `(also)` in the other tag's definition in the suggested tags window, or does it *only* replace tags in questions globally?

Comment: I found [this description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/303080) of the process and I'm trying to read through it now... but if you can look at this particular example `near-earth-asteroid` vs `neo` - I don't even know which I should suggest is a synonym to which (If I even could) in order to raise the question!

Comment: It's tricky for sure. Start by clicking tags, then synonyms.